# How to handle optional parts with Instaparse?

Tags: clojure

I would like to parse the following source:

```
unit SystemGeneralAR;
interface
    uses AbstractRecord, OracleData, systemgeneral_auto_gen;
    type
      TSystemGeneral = class(TSystemGeneralbase)
      public
         destructor Destroy; override;
         class function All(): ISystemGeneralResultSet; reintroduce;
     end; 
 implementation 
      uses testa, testb; 
 end.
```

The problem is, that the uses list can apear but must not. I tried to change uses to [uses] but that would give me an emtpy uses list, even if one exists.

BTW: my grammar looks like this:

```
 S = unit-decl interface<any>*implementation<any>*<'.'>

 unit-decl = 'unit'<space>*identifier<space>*<';'>
 unit-name = identifier

 interface = <interface_dec> uses
 interface_dec = <space>*'interface'<space>*

 implementation = <'implementation'>impl_body
 impl_body = uses

 uses = <space>*<'uses'><space>*uses_list
 uses_list = (uses_element<','>)*(uses_element<';'>)
 uses_element = <space>*identifier<space>*

 identifier = #'[A-Za-z|_]+'
 space = #' '
 any = #'[A-Za-z|_| |,|;|=|(|)|:]'
```

The resulting parse tree, with uses* looks like this:

```
 [:S [:unit-decl "unit" [:identifier "SystemGeneralAR"]] [:interface] 
 [:implementation [:impl_body]]]
```

With just uses it looks like:

```
[:S
 [:unit-decl "unit" [:identifier "SystemGeneralAR"]]
 [:interface
  [:uses
   [:uses_list
    [:uses_element [:identifier "AbstractRecord"]]
    [:uses_element [:identifier "OracleData"]]
    [:uses_element [:identifier "systemgeneral_auto_gen"]]]]]
 [:implementation
  [:impl_body [:uses [:uses_list [:uses_element [:identifier "testa"]] [:uses_element [:identifier "testb"]]]]]]]
```

Comment: make users have cardinality of 0 or more (e.g. `uses*`)

Comment: The uses_list is empty even if there is one in the soruce code if I change uses to uses*

Comment: Can you put the resulting parse tree in your question?

Comment: Ahhhhh... so you just don't want to see `:uses_list` correct?

Comment: Yes, I don't wan't to see it, if there is no uses statement in the source code.

Comment: Then it should work if you put `<uses_list>` as the non-terminal instead of `uses_list`. What that will do is only put uses but not the `uses_list` container in the parse tree. To do something that is conditional (in other words you want to see `uses_list` if there ARE `uses` you need a slightly richer non-terminal model or expression. So it comes down to your business rule. Please specify exact behavior you are looking for.

Comment: That is exactly my problem. I want to see uses_list if there ARE uses.

Comment: Got it. I will use the answer to provide a recommendation

Comment: To the comment to my post. I agree. I make it a habit *not* to name non-terminals the same as terminals just for readability alone. Good luck, you are close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roger

Here is a valid, tested use case grammar. I tried using what you have but it is failing and doesn't appear complete. Following this are two examples to demonstrate optional appearance if condition exists:

```
S = A <space> B [<space> optC]

A = "a"

B = "b"

C = "c"

optC = C

space = #' '
```

Here are the two outputs:

```
;input 1 = "a b"
;produces

=> [:S [:A "a"] [:B "b"]]

input 2 = "a b c"
;produces

=> [:S [:A "a"] [:B "b"] [:optC [:C "c"]]]
```

***With your grammar. As I said, I was having trouble as it does not appear fully defined but generally speaking:***

```
(* If you change this *)

interface = <interface_dec> uses

(* to this, you should get similar results *)

interface = <interface_dec> [uses]
```

If that doesn't work then you would need to provide a grammar that works with the input sample provided as they seem out of synch.

Comment: Thanks. I'll now try to figure out what's the problem is with my grammar. I think it has something to do with the placement of terminal and non-terminal symbols.